# How to import .sql to .sqlite in mac

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

Can anyone let me know how we can convert .sql database file into .sqlite file in mac.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to find out the format of your .sql file, in order to convert it. Possibly it's already in sqlite format, and you just need to rename the file.

Comment: Hi Graham, we tried what you said but its not working

Comment: Is the .sql file a script with `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes it is a script with create and insert statements.

Comment: What DBMS was the .sql file generated from?

Comment: Hi Chris, no idea about DBMS as its given by client but .sql file have been generated through PHP Version: 5.2.4.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're converting from MySQL, try this: http://www.jbip.net/content/how-convert-mysql-sqlite

There are a handful of keywords supported in MySQL that aren't supported in sqlite.

Comment: Edit your question to include the file contents.

Comment: Hi Chris, we looked into your link which you send the problem is the unique key as well as primary key we cant get these in our .sql file as it is encrypted. We want to ask for one more favour will it be possible for you to import the file if we send you the file.